# Visual Studio 2008 start debugging change associated executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, the first time I hit F5 (Start debugging), it asks me what executable i would like to debug. I entered a wrong one and now the wrong executable is run everytime I start debugging. Is there a way to change it?

(My project is a cmake-generated big C++ project)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solution: Common Properties -> Startup Project -> Single startup project -> *choose the correct project*

For project: Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command -> *navigate to path of .exe you want to launch*

I hope this helps!

Comment: For the first, you can also just right click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Set as Startup Project"